# Is it possible to only display part of a webpage ?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, browser, windows-phone

Hi Im trying write an App which features a small WebBrowsers element. What I want to do is only display a part of a specific webpage.

Is there a way to crop(a lack for a better term) what is shown to the user?

Ps. I've tried to mess around with WebBrowser.Clip(i dont know even know if its the right method for this), but so far no success. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you correctly, you are doing this:

You have a WebView in you'r app.
You navigate to some page using link? Like www.****

If yes, then you should go this way:

Make a request to your link, to get HTML of a certain page:

```
string pageHTML = HttpClient.GetResponse() // something like that.
```

Now you have pages HTML and you can modify it as you like, implement JS scripts etc...

```
pageHTML = pageHTMLmodified;
```

And next you do this:

```
WebBrowser.NavigateToString(pageHTML);
```

If i correctly understood your question